# How to unlink Google app account from my profile

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

I have a personal Gmail account and my company has a Google App account. I made the mistake once of logging into the Gapps and now it is forever linked to my personal account. I want to sever that linkage forever so that I never have to select the account to use when using any Web Application.

More specifics:

1. I've deleted and recreated my Chrome profile many times. Initially, only my personal account is listed (from the profile, but let some time pass and my gapps account becomes linked and dominant.
2. This issue does not occur on my Chrome book, Canary or on my system at home, only Stable on my work machine.
3. This may or may not be relevant, but I use both Chrome stable and Chrome Canary on my work system.

Comment: You could try changing passwords, which would prevent the automatic log-in.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend deleting the Chrome Profiles manually (in AppData). As this isn't happening on other installs (Canary) or devices (other PCs and Chrome OS), you can narrow this down to being a local issue.

If it's possible in your work environment, uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome Stable completely should also resolve this.